# parsing html table tr tag missing

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I need to parse a `html` table using php. But after 1st record, last few records does not have starting `<tr>` tag. Below is the code:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
    <td class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>4228651391</td>
    <td>Payment</td>
    <td>01850147130</td>
    <td>01670808080</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>lcghs786</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>18-feb-16 21:37:52</td>
</tr>
    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
    <td class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>4226429613</td>
    <td>Payment</td>
    <td>01957814120</td>
    <td>01670808080</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>aims777</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>18-feb-16 17:44:12</td>
</tr>
    <td class="dragHandle"></td>
    <td class="checkbox"></td>
    <td>4226292073</td>
    <td>Payment</td>
    <td>01957814120</td>
    <td>01670808080</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>AIMS786</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>18-feb-16 17:28:02</td>
</tr>
```

I tried with `simple_html_dom` library but it only return `array` for the first record. Please help me how to parse all the records and put in an `array`.
Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to parse broken HTML you're going to have a bad time of it... :|

Comment: Is there *any* way to make the HTML valid before trying to parse it?  Where are you getting invalid HTML?  If a DOM parser can't make sense of it because it's invalid then you may be down to manual string parsing.  Maybe explode it into an array of strings on the `'</tr>'` and try parsing each segment individually?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need fill missing `tr` to your html by this library.

> http://htmlpurifier.org/

Then using code below

```
$content = str_get_html(your html);
$tr_array = $content->find('tr');
foreach($tr_array as $tr) {
   //process your tr data
};
```

Comment: Any suggestion how to add the missing <tr> in my html and then parsing. Parsing was no problem, but I need a easy way to repair the missing tags

Comment: In the htmlpurifier document: `require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';`

`$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();`
`$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);`
`$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);`

Comment: use a library for easy way to repair it

Comment: I tried the library. This also eventually returns One record only. :(

Answer (score 0):

At last I could solve the problem. Thanks for the hint from @Kelvin

I have taken the faulty static html page [output.html] and fed it to html fixing application called 'tidy' . For parsing th data to a PHP 'array' I used table2arr library by Wojtek Jarzecki in phpclasses.org.

Corrected working code as below.

---

require_once 'table2arr.php';

$string=file_get_contents('output.html');

shell_exec("tidy.exe output.html > test.html");

$clean_html=file_get_contents('test.html');

$g= new table2arr($clean_html);

$cnt=$g->tablecount;

for($i=0;$i

$g->getcells($i);

var_dump($g->cells);
  }